# Given an NSManagedObject with optional to-one relationships, how do I check if they are empty or not?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

This is a purely theoretical 'what if' question, so no pressure to rush to an answer.  I'd prefer an answer that works in the context of a subclassed NSManagedObject, but I'll accept one that's based on the parent.

I know that if the relationship is to-many, I simply check and see the count of the NS(Ordered)Set, but when you have a to-one relationship, I'm not sure what I'd do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if it is nil or not.

Comment: That's so obvious, I'm not sure how I overlooked it -- probably because I was looking through the methods of the NSManagedObject class.  THanks!